# How to get the email content as EML or MSG from the exchange server using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, outlook, exchangewebservices, outlook-addin, office-addins

I want to get the content of an email in the `.msg` format in my `Node` app. Currently I send the following SOAP request to get an html version of the email:

```
const getEmailContentSOAP = `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
  xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">
    <soap:Header>
        <RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2013"
          xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types"
          soap:mustUnderstand="0" />
      </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <GetItem
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages"
      xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">
      <ItemShape>
        <t:BaseShape>Default</t:BaseShape>
        <t:IncludeMimeContent>true</t:IncludeMimeContent>
      </ItemShape>
      <ItemIds>
        <t:ItemId Id="${emailID}" />
      </ItemIds>
    </GetItem>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>`;
```

Is there a way to directly get the .msg version or convert this to .msg?

Comment: Not sure if something like this exists already but you can always write your own converter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No the MSG format is an Office File format (Compound file format https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_File_Binary_Format which is not trivial to generate) so generally using Outlook or Redemption is the only practical way of doing this along with the only real reason people usually try to use the MSG format is to maintain fidelity of MAPI properties and Attachment types which you will need MAPI for.

For what you doing with EWS the content you get back with the IncludeMimeContent is the MIMEConent of the Message which can just be saved as an EML file and thus opened in any email client that support EML including Outlook which is generally sufficient for most thing (excluding Migration).

Answer (score 2):

It's in beta and there isn't a documentation, but you can get MIME content with Microsoft Graph API:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/messages/{id}/$value
```

or

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/{id | userPrincipalName}/messages/{id}/$value
```

You can try with [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer), setting version to beta.
Then you can save the response as a .eml file.

**Edit:**

Now it's officially in preview: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/outlook-get-mime-message

Answer (score 1):

As Glen says, generate EML format email. I already did it and it works nice with different mail clients (SharePoint also has preview mode for .eml files!).

I would recommend you to use the [Microsoft Graph API](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/mail_api_overview) to obtain all the mail data, so you can generate the .eml mail.

API call example to get a single mail data with the attachments:

`` `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages/${messageId}?$expand=attachments` ``

Then convert it.

You have more data available at:

[MSGraph Message docs](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/message)

[MSGraph Message attachments docs](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/message_list_attachments)

[MSGraph quick starts (includes node and angular)](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/get-started)

Comment: Hi @mikel, I was able to get the single mail data with the attachments, however, I'm still confused with the 'converting part'. How can i convert the API response to .eml file ??

Comment: Then you can generate the .eml file with all the data you get from it. Here is an example of how a mail can look as .eml https://www.phpclasses.org/browse/file/14672.html. You can use rfc1521 https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1521.txt